Facing issue converting Sitecore10.1 JSS NextJS Project into Native Mobile Code using Capacitor JS
I have followed the below steps:
For Creating Sitecore10.1 JSS NextJS Project:
npm i -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@18.0.0

jss create testapp nextjs --branch release/18.0.0

jss start

For Converting the Project using CapacitorJS:
npm i -D @capacitor/cli@latest-5

npm i @capacitor/core@latest-5

npx cap init

npm i @capacitor/android@latest-5

npx cap add android

When I run this command then getting below Error
√ Adding native android project in android in 84.02ms

√ add in 85.19ms

× copy android - failed!

[error] The web assets directory (.\public) must contain an index.html file.
        It will be the entry point for the web portion of the Capacitor app.
√ Updating Android plugins in 15.59ms

× update android - failed!

[error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
        'C:\Repos\JSS\testapp\android\app\src\main\assets\capacitor.plugins.json'

Can anyone please guide me on this?
